# How do I set a Content Type Charset in Ktor client (Not an accept charset)

Tags: kotlin, character-encoding, ktor

A beginner here, 
Is there any other way of adding Content-Type Charset instead of doing `header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")` ?

```
val client = HttpClient {
            Charsets {
                Charsets.UTF_8
            } // This sets the accept header only, does not set the content type charset
        }
 client.put<HttpResponse> {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            url(url)
            body =body
        }
```

This however works

```
 client.put<HttpResponse> {
            header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            url(url)
            body = body
        }
```

Would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

To specify the header using the Ktor API, you have to give it a parameter:

```
client.put<HttpResponse> {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json.withParameter("charset", "utf-8"))
    url(url)
    body = body
}
```